# Request Body NSDictionary adding json Values

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary

How to make request body for **NSDictionary**

```
NSDictionary *requestBody =
  @{ 
    @"device": @"iPhone"        
    @"pincode": @"123456"
    @"bottle": @"Milton"
    @"taglists": { @"2": @[@"NO", @"YES"]};
  };
```

**Its gives an error 'taglists Expected ' or ;**

> How to create dict in **json** format using key value pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the `comma` after one `key-value` pair and `@`before the nested `taglists` dictionary also put semicolon at the end of the statement.

```
NSDictionary *requestBody =
  @{ 
    @"device": @"iPhone",        
    @"pincode": @"123456",
    @"bottle": @"Milton",
    @"taglists": @{ @"2": @[@"NO", @"YES"]}
  };
```

Comment: @KkMIW Welcome mate :)